# unable to connect to server (error-404)

Tags: java, servlets

I created a sample Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse, but when I am running my project with Tomcat 5.5 i am getting this error:

> ### HTTP Status 404 - /greetingservlet/
>
> type Status report
>   message /greetingservlet/
>   description The requested resource (/greetingservlet/) is not available.

My HTML/JSP source code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE greeting SYSTEM "hello.dtd">
<html>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<body BGCOLOR="YELLOW">
<center>
<h1>USER NAME ENTRY SREEN</h1>
<form action="./greet">
user name<input type="text" name="t1">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="get message">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My servlet source code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Greetingservlt
 */
public class Greetingservlt extends GenericServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
    IOException
    {
        String name=request.getParameter("t1");
        response.setContentType("text");
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<body bgcolor=wheat>");
        pw.println("<h1>HELLO " +  name  + "  WELCOME</h1>");
        pw.println("</html>");
        pw.close();

    }



}
```

My `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app SYSTEM "Web-app.dtd">
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Greetingapplication</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping id="ServletMapping_1283534546609">
<servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/greet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

The servlet is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/greet`, not `/greetingservlet` as you seem to expect as per the error message.  So, change the URL in browser address bar accordingly. Also, the servlet class is declared to be `Greetingapplication`, but it has the actual name `Greetingservlt`. So, you need to align out the one or the other, otherwise Tomcat is unable to locate/load the servlet. Also, packageless servlet classes used to fail on some specific Tomcat + JVM combinations. To be on the safe side, you'd like to place the servlet class (as every other Java class) in a `package` (don't forget to update the `web.xml` accordingly).

<sub>There are more problems in the code posted as far, but they are as far not relevant to this particular question. Maybe in a new question.</sub>

Comment: I thought you missed the class name discrepancy so I rewrote my answer, but you didn't, and here is my +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The **404** or **Not Found** HTTP response code indicates that the client **was** able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find the resource that was requested. And indeed...

First, according to your `web.xml`, your Servlet is mapped on `/greet`, and not `/greetingservlet`. So why are you trying to access `/greetingservlet`? Is this the name of your JSP? If yes, it's missing the `.jsp` extension. If no, then you should probably use `/greet` instead.

Second, your `web.xml` doesn't look correct, the `servlet-class` doesn't match the actual name of your servlet. It should be:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
  <display-name>My First Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.acme.Greetingservlt</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Replace `com.acme` with the real package of your servlet, if any(!). And redeploy the whole.

As a reminder, the URL to access the servlet is constructed like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/greet
           A       B     C       D
```

Where:

- A is the hostname where Tomcat is running (the local machine here)
- B is the port Tomcat is listening to (8080 is the default)
- C is the context path of your webapp (the name of the war by default)
- D is the pattern declared in the web.xml to invoke the servlet

Comment: If you fix the `web.xml` to comply Tomcat 5.5, you get a +1 as well :)